# Cannot perform correctly a View transition after playing a video in ViewDidLoad

Tags: xcode, video, view

I'm playing a video opening my app inserting following code in viewDidLoad..

```
    NSURL *video = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iPad - Tracks" ofType:@"m4v"]];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:video];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view insertSubview:moviePlayer.view atIndex:0];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

The problem is that:

1) If I let the video easily end, and then I call a transition like..

```
-(IBAction)vai_iPad_CosaFacc{
if (iPad_onAir != iPad_CosaFacc){
    [UIView transitionFromView:iPad_onAir
                        toView:iPad_CosaFacc
                      duration:0.5 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
    iPad_onAir  = iPad_CosaFacc;
    [iPad_CosaFacc_WebV loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iPad_CosaFacciamo" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
    [iPad_CosaFacc_WebV setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

}

..everything is OK.

2) If I stop the video, and only in this case.. after the removeFromSuperview of my video, animation has a problem: if I load a new view with UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft then i can see the new view in my iPad screen before the transition has ended, and I cannot understand why.

Can somebody help me?

THanks